# How to handle OAuthAccountNotLinked error in a Next.js app with NextAuth, Prisma, and MongoDB?

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js application that uses NextAuth for authentication and Prisma with MongoDB for database management. The app supports authentication through Github and credentials. However, if a user creates an account using their email, they are unable to log in with a third-party app and receive the OAuthAccountNotLinked error.

What is the best way to handle this error? Specifically, how can I display a custom text message or send a toast notification to the user to inform them of the issue and provide instructions on how to resolve it?

edit/
I tried to create an async function, then await for a response, but I doesn't seem to work. I have no Idea how can I do it..

```
    const handleGithubLogin = async () => {
    await signIn("github", { redirect: false })
    .then(async (res) => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log("Here")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("Error here")
    })
    
}
```

I've tried it in other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

A soulution I've found is something like this:

```
const { error } = useRouter().query

if(error) {
   toast("Error")
}
```

however, the problem is that, instead of having only 1 toast, i get 4 of them (or 2) and I'm not sure why.